# Creating an image from an HTML document at runtime

Tags: php, html, runtime, shared-hosting

I am currently working on a website project that requires the creation of an image based on user input on a form. Basically, I'm trying to create an image from existing HTML markup with the form data replacing some of text. The text is almost always unique.

I have explored several options for creating such an image, mainly:

1. `imagecreate` with PHP that wasn't flexible enough, and
2. PhantomJS which I can't really install on the server
3. wkhtmltopdf and php-wkhtmltox

I am working in a shared-hosting environment that limit my available options. The environment supports PHP (compiled with GD), Perl, and Python.

Is there a reliable way to implement such a behavior?

Comment: You've tried wkhtmltopdf, but have you tried wkhtmltoimg?  If so, what didn't work out?  They include precompiled binaries that work pretty much anywhere without complex installation...

Comment: @Charles: Yes, both. I couldn't execute them through PHP - although succeeded in running them locally through the console

Comment: That's a shame, they're really awesome (for the price -- free, that is).

Comment: @Charles: I agree. I think the main problem is the shared-hosting environment which severely limits my options. It seems that my only option right now is finding a service with an API interface.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) software to render images from html, it works perfectly. The only issue is that you need to build it on your shared hosting. Probably the workaround could be in building it on your local machine, uploading it to your hosting and running it from there, but I don't believe it will work, because it requires X server.

Another possible solution could be use of [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) to build the image manually. If you know how your html is looks like, you can replicate it by drawing all elements on a blank image. It is not easy to do, but looks like this is only one solution which you can use.

Comment: From my trials, the GD library don't give me the flexibility I require for this application. But I'll try to give it another go.